# Share authenticated session between multiple instances using OpenID Connect

Tags: authentication, session, openid-connect

I have an application that is scaled out (deployed) in two separate servers.
I have a load balancer in front of these two servers (uses round-robin). However, I don't have access to this load balancer right now to set up or configure anything here. (let's say it's abstract and remains so).

Now, I have installed 'Apache + OpenID Connect' in the two servers where my application is running. So, the web server setup is also complete with the application server setup behind it. This is all working fine now.

My scenario is that, say a browser request B1 arrives at the load balancer and reaches server, S1, behind it. The request is redirected to an SSO Identity Provider, successfully authenticated there and returns back to S1 to serve the resources protected here (when server S2 behind load balancer is not running).

My question is - how can I ensure that even while I have server S2 up and running alongwith S1, the successful authentication be made to understood by S2 (though the original authentication redirection was made by S1)?
i.e: no matter who authenticates (S1 or S2), one successful authentication cycle should serve the same protected resources residing in both the servers.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't really matter about openid-connect, it's mostly about how you manage sessions or login state.  Do you have sessions server-side?  Are you storing an authentication token in a cookie or local storage?  As long as both back end servers have access to common information to validate a session (a common session DB, or common keys to validate client tokens, or something else) it should be fine.

Comment: @Joe the implementation and configuration of Apache's openidconnect plugin is very much at play here. If the cluster is configured for session replication, it may fall back to OIDC to determine whether it not it can establish the user's session on a second node.

Comment: Your question is not trivial and requires very specific knowledge of Apache and its OIDC implementation to provide a reliable answer. You might not receive one.